# Usage of Picture in my book

Tags: discussion

Can I use the Konstantin Korotkov  photograph of the life force leaving a dead body in my book? as it says on the internet free to use and share.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The copyright on that [picture](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17903/did-konstantin-korotkov-take-a-photograph-of-the-life-force-leaving-a-dead-body)  does not belong to Stack Exchange Inc. or the users of the Stack Exchange Network, so we are unable to grant you that permission. However, the [original source](http://www.sciencephoto.com/media/287461/view) has been provided, so you can follow it back to find the original copyright owner to seek permission and pay royalties.

Why are we able to put the photo on this site given we don't own the copyright?  [Fair Use](http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/) provisions allow reproduction for comment and criticism.

(On a related matter: it hasn't happened for a while, but I have occasionally delete photos from questions and answers that weren't part of a claim, but were added to a question for "flavour", because that isn't a "fair use" of the photo - unless they were sourced with an appropriate license.)